# DHCP discover not being answered through repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, dhcp-server

I am currently stuck with a fairly crappy router/modem combo from a German ISP. In order to get good WiFi signal in all rooms, I have installed a second access point, using an old router in bridge mode.

1. Modem/Router - `192.168.1.1` / DHCP (`192.168.1.[3-254]`) + NAT on
2. AP/Repeater - `192.168.1.2` (Def. Gateway + DNS `192.168.1.1`) / DHCP + NAT off

I can connect through (1) directly, but if I switch over to the AP, the `DHCP Discover` requests from my device do not get an answer, and I'm left without an IP. Configuring an IP manually without DHCP works as expected both through the router and through the AP.

I've realized that when a device tries to get an IP via DHCP from behind the repeater, the repeater itself replaces the source MAC address of the DHCP packets:

- should an access point in such a network topology actually be replacing the MAC address of the DHCP packets? As it's all a single subnet, I assumed the packets would be forwarded as they are.
- if MAC address replacement makes sense - the router already has its fixed IP. How can the DHCP server know that the DHCP discover requests actually come from a device *behind* the AP and not from the AP itself? The source MAC address is the same!

Comment: While (1) is an unbranded PYUR/Telecolumbus router, the AP (2) I'm using is an ASUS RT-AC66U.

Comment: I used to own that ASUS RT-AC66U, It's a complete piece of garbage. I RMAed it 4 times. My recommendation is take a hammer to it, and thank me later.

Comment: Change the subnet of the Repeater and see what happens. Meaning the AP repeater IP address being 192.168.1.2 is fine. but the IP addresses it gives out should be of a differenet subnet, like 192.168.0.1. or 192.168.2.1. Or disable DHCP from your reaper and make it a true repeater. Repeaters are not supposed to have DHCP enabled from what I remember.

Comment: The router isn’t in “bridge” mode if that is what it is doing. You need to do this the way it’s usually done. I’m not sure what Asus is calling bridge mode, but it’s not. Instead you need to hook it up like this: leave the WAN port unhooked, change the LAN IP of the asus to an unused address on 192.168.1.x. Disable DHCP. Plug the asus’s LAN port in to a LAN port on your other router. Now THAT is a bridge. You’re not clear if you are using some type of “repeater” mode but it would not be needed in this config.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use cables in this setup. The Asus is picking up the WiFi signal of the router and repeating it downstream. DHCP is already disabled on the repeater.

Comment: Is it possible to return that Router? Asking for a friend :)